# object detection for games

Tags: python, object-detection

I want to create an AI for flappy bird and I want to it using object detection and a neural network (I know it is not the most effective way, but this is the way I need to do it).
I used the ImageAI python module but it didn't really do what I wanted to do.
my code is:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "image.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "imagenew.jpg"))

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] , " : " , eachObject["percentage_probability"] )
```

and I gave it this image to see if it knows that this is an object:

[pipe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upPoW.png)

but it didn't do anything with it.

So my question is: is there anything that can detect objects with out a database?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a NN that can play the game? You're aware of how vast that topic is?

Comment: No I am asking for help in object detection, I have everthing else set up for it